# Adding options to AJAX form after initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajaxform

I'm using [this](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) jQuery form plugin to submit forms using ajax on my single page application, and I need to add a function to be called on successful submission. I know that options can be added at initialization by including the function with options passed to the form using:

```
var options = { 
    success:    function() { 
        myFunction(); 
    } 
}; 
$('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
```

However, I can't do this as the form is being initialized by [this](https://swebdeveloper.com/apps/forms-plus-js/) framework which I'm using. As such, I need to add the function after initialization. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if so how to do it?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myForm').ajaxForm({
    success: function(res, status, xhr, form) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly the same as the approach which I said in my question I cant do as this is initializing the form. As it's already initialized through the Forms Plus framework, it ends up getting submitted twice.

Answer (score 0):

In case it's helpful for anyone else, there are callbacks exposed already in that framework:

```
$('#form').on({
fpAjaxDone: function ( e, jqXHR, status, data ){
    successFunction();
},
fpAjaxFail: function ( e, jqXHR, status, data ){
    failFunction();
}
});
```